# java.awt , swing, and Apache POI for Power Point Presentation

Tags: swing, powerpoint, awt, apache-poi

I'm trying to use SlideShow to create presentation...

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/SlideShow.html

and I see some uses of `java.awt` classes in the examples.

My question is: to what extent awt can be used in creating PPT using POI?

Further, how swing can be used together with Apache POI?

Could some experts enlighten me in this direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWT is used for computing the dimensions of elements, it doesn't actually draw anything on the screen.